# very Slow Mysql INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

This query works fine on my local dev machine, but takes ages on the remote server and seems to time out the server with an error 500, is there a better way to write this select statement?, any advice would be greatly received.

thanx

J

```
<?php

$members = new WA_MySQLi_RS("members",$alpha,1);

$members->setQuery("SELECT
registration.*,
child_base_survey.*,
child_base_scas.*,
child_base_smqf.*,
parent_base_survey.*,
parent_base_ippa.*,
parent_base_eac.*,
parent_base_scas.*,
parent_base_smqf.*,
parent_base_eval.*,
user_access_level.*,
parent_one_month_survey.*,
parent_one_month_ippa.*,
parent_one_month_eac.*,
parent_one_month_eval.*,
child_three_month_survey.*,
child_three_month_scas.*,
child_three_month_smqf.*,
parent_three_month_survey.*,
parent_three_month_scas.*,
parent_three_month_smqf.*,
parent_three_month_eval.*,
cron.*
FROM registration
INNER JOIN child_base_survey ON registration.rego_parent_uid = child_base_survey.child_base_survey_uid
INNER JOIN child_base_scas ON child_base_survey.child_base_survey_uid = child_base_scas.child_base_scas_uid
INNER JOIN child_base_smqf ON child_base_scas.child_base_scas_uid = child_base_smqf.child_base_smqf_uid
INNER JOIN parent_base_survey ON child_base_smqf.child_base_smqf_uid = parent_base_survey.parent_base_survey_uid
INNER JOIN parent_base_ippa ON parent_base_survey.parent_base_survey_uid = parent_base_ippa.parent_base_ippa_uid
INNER JOIN parent_base_eac ON parent_base_ippa.parent_base_ippa_uid = parent_base_eac.parent_base_eac_uid
INNER JOIN parent_base_scas ON parent_base_eac.parent_base_eac_uid = parent_base_scas.parent_base_scas_uid
INNER JOIN parent_base_smqf ON parent_base_scas.parent_base_scas_uid = parent_base_smqf.parent_base_smqf_uid
INNER JOIN parent_base_eval ON parent_base_smqf.parent_base_smqf_uid = parent_base_eval.parent_base_eval_uid
INNER JOIN user_access_level ON parent_base_eval.parent_base_eval_uid = user_access_level.user_access_level_uid
INNER JOIN parent_one_month_survey ON user_access_level.user_access_level_uid = parent_one_month_survey.parent_one_month_survey_uid
INNER JOIN parent_one_month_ippa ON parent_one_month_survey.parent_one_month_survey_uid = parent_one_month_ippa.parent_one_month_ippa_uid
INNER JOIN parent_one_month_eac ON parent_one_month_ippa.parent_one_month_ippa_uid = parent_one_month_eac.parent_one_month_eac_uid
INNER JOIN parent_one_month_eval ON parent_one_month_eac.parent_one_month_eac_uid = parent_one_month_eval.parent_one_month_eval_uid
INNER JOIN child_three_month_survey ON parent_one_month_eval.parent_one_month_eval_uid = child_three_month_survey.child_three_month_survey_uid
INNER JOIN child_three_month_scas ON child_three_month_survey.child_three_month_survey_uid = child_three_month_scas.child_three_month_scas_uid
INNER JOIN child_three_month_smqf ON child_three_month_scas.child_three_month_scas_uid = child_three_month_smqf.child_three_month_smqf_uid
INNER JOIN parent_three_month_survey ON child_three_month_smqf.child_three_month_smqf_uid = parent_three_month_survey.parent_three_month_survey_uid
INNER JOIN parent_three_month_scas ON parent_three_month_survey.parent_three_month_survey_uid = child_three_month_smqf.child_three_month_smqf_uid
INNER JOIN parent_three_month_smqf ON parent_three_month_scas.parent_three_month_scas_uid = parent_three_month_smqf.parent_three_month_smqf_uid
INNER JOIN parent_three_month_eval ON parent_three_month_smqf.parent_three_month_smqf_uid = parent_three_month_eval.parent_three_month_eval_uid
INNER JOIN cron ON parent_three_month_eval.parent_three_month_eval_uid = cron.cron_uid");

?>
```

Comment: Are all table columns necessary? If not, select only the useful one.

Comment: yes all tables are necessary (i think) as when the user registration takes place the .uid for each table is set so I can make queries across all tables and update the content when they complete surveys, I'm new to MYSQL sorry if it's bad code :-( is there a way to only add the registration.uid at registration and still get a mysql result?.

Comment: I mean the columns, you selected all (registration.*,
child_base_survey.*, etc).

Comment: ah no not at registration no... all i need is child_base_survey.child_base_survey_uid
child_base_scas.child_base_scas_uid etc.... would that make a large difference?

Comment: yes its better to select only the necessary columns, it saves execution time :)

Comment: Aside from the columns issue (which should make some difference), the query cannot be improved without structural change. However, the appropriate provision of indexes should help considerably. But to help with that we'd need to see the EXPLAIN and, really, table creation statements. I suggest you start again, build the query adding a table each time and see at what point it starts to get slow. Then ping us the EXPLAIN for that query.

Comment: cool thanx ill try that you and see if it gets better. J

Comment: @user994770 you need to look at your server error logs to see why it failed. anything else is speculation

Comment: Yes, look at the server logs. Also, how many rows are actually returned by this query? A simple query with a very large result set will be processed quickly by a local machine, but much more slowly from a remote server, depending on the network setup. And are you comparing apples with apples, i.e. is the content of your local database identical to the content of your server database? If you only have three rows of test data locally, it's going to be quick compared to a terabyte of data on the server...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are missing a where clause.  As it is, it is fetching all the data.  And from comments above it seems you are running out of memory.  Shouldn't you be filtering it for one user ?  Or try a limit of 1 for testing - just to prove that query is okay in itself.

Comment: the LIMIT is set here $members = new WA_MySQLi_RS("members",$alpha,1);
WA_MySQLi_RS($name, $con, $Max_Rows);

Comment: Would you please  tell us how many rows you have in each of the tables.please.

Comment: approx 100 chars per table

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the hosting company has been having server issues. hence the error 500 and timeouts,

thank you all for your help and insights.

J

Answer (score 0):

It's a very bad query, of course, but 500 error is not an TimeOut error. 500 - Internal Server Error, mean your script hangs after memory limit or segmentation fault.

Look at the server php error log for more information.

Comment: It's a large query. But, structural issues aside, it's not a bad one.

Comment: it's not even a particularly complex query - so long as all those join fields are indexed it should be fine.

Comment: every foo.foo_uid is indexed and set to primary key & auto increment.

still the remote server times out.. very odd, like i said works fine local..?